# What does a proxy mean in Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, proxy

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#notes-on-proxies says

> Some of the objects provided by Flask are proxies to other objects. The proxies are accessed in the same way for each worker thread, but point to the unique object bound to each worker behind the scenes as described on this page.

Is "proxy" a concept in Python language or somewhere else (such as design patterns)?

What is its definition?

Does Python  provide some language features that support proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The note tells about [proxy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) — having [lighweight] object that passes calls to some other underlying object, and/or delegate some work.

Having additional logic in proxy makes it adjacent pattern to adapter, having multiple objects "behind" is adjacent to router.